# Azure application Insights to log between two different resource groups

Tags: azure, logging, resources, azure-application-insights

Our group uses Azure application insights for logging our resources in azure. We also have a separate resource group that basicaly mirrors the main resource group but is used for our DR failover. Because it mirrors the main resource group, there is a lot of similar naming with a -dr on the end of the name. We were hoping to use a single Application Insights resource to store the logs from both resource groups. Ideally, we would also like to supply some tagging within application Insights to differentiate the logs between the different resource groups. I am looking for documentation online and see information about different regions, but not about using the same AI between resource groups. Any ideas? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation you have some options:

- Add custom tags to the telemetry to differentiate between the environments. You can do this using a [Telemetry Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) but you need to write code to do that. So that might not be possible for all the resources you are tracking.
- Use one of the common fields like cloud_RoleName or cloud_RoleInstance to differentiate between the environments. As I understand, for your DR failover you have resources that have name that ends with "-dr". So you can do something like `requests | extend environment = iif(cloud_RoleName  endswith "-prod", "production", "test")`.

Comment: Thank you! Another quick question, do you know if Application Insights itself has an automatic failover process out of the box? So if we do use a single AI instance and that region goes down, would  that AI resource go down as well?